# unable to return 0 when no data found in inner query of pivot table, used coalesce as well... but no luck

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

Added Actual sample table,along with sample result ....

```
SELECT 'RESULT' AS Ratio, coalesce([colData1],0) data1, 
    coalesce([colData2],0) data2, coalesce([colData4],0) data4, 
    coalesce([colData7],0) data7 
FROM (SELECT columnName1,columnName2 FROM table 
where columnName3 = 'ABC' and columnName4='def' and columnName5='fgh' ) AS 
    SREC PIVOT ( sum(columnName2) FOR columnName1 IN ([colData1],colData2 
,    colData4 ,colData7 ) ) AS PVT
```

Sample Table:
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oquph.png)
Table
Result:
[Sample Result for above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNW5c.png)

--###################################################

Now If I  my change my query:

```
SELECT 'RESULT' AS Ratio, coalesce([colData1],0) data1,
coalesce([colData2],0) data2,
coalesce([colData4],0) data4,
coalesce([colData7],0) data7
    FROM (SELECT  columnName1,columnName2 
          FROM table where columnName3 = 'DEF'   and columnName4='def' and columnName5='fgh'
         ) AS SREC
    PIVOT 
    (
      sum(columnName2) 
      FOR columnName1 IN ([colData1],colData2   ,colData4   ,colData7   )
    ) AS PVT
```

Then it should display: all pivot column data as 0 ...

As I've 29 unique data values for columnName1, I'm just trying to use pivot table instead individual case statements.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #YourTable
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , ColumnName1 VARCHAR(20)
    , ColumnName2 INT
    , ColumnName3 VARCHAR(20)
    , ColumnName4 VARCHAR(20)
    , ColumnName5 VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #YourTable
VALUES
    ('colData1', 1, 'ABC', 'def', 'fgh')
    , ('colData2', 1, 'ABC', 'def', 'fgh')
    , ('colData1', 1, 'ABC', 'def', 'fgh')
    , ('colData4', 1, 'ABC', 'def', 'fgh')
    , ('colData1', 1, 'ABC', 'def', 'fgh')
    , ('colData4', 1, 'ABC', 'def', 'fgh')
    , ('colData7', 1, 'ABC', 'def', 'fgh')
    , ('colData1', 0, 'ABC', 'def', 'fgh')

SELECT 
    Ratio
    , coalesce([colData1],0) data1 
    , coalesce([colData2],0) data2
    , coalesce([colData4],0) data4
    , coalesce([colData7],0) data7 
FROM (SELECT 'Result' AS Ratio) x
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            columnName1
            ,columnName2 
        FROM #yourtable 
        where columnName3 = 'ABC' 
            and columnName4='def' 
            and columnName5='fgh' 
        ) AS SREC 
        PIVOT ( 
            sum(columnName2) 
            FOR columnName1 IN ([colData1],[colData2],[colData4] ,[colData7] ) 
        ) AS PVT
    ) PVT ON 1=1
```

Explanation:
To return a row regardless of if you have data or not, you first have to ensure you return a row.  In your result table, you have a column that is always returned with a static value.  Turns this into a table (done in the nested join) and left join on this with some condition the word `'RESULT'` is always returned.

I am assuming you're only returning one row, so I just return anything that comes out of the result set of the left join with a `1=1`

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT 'RESULT' AS Ratio,
       SUM(CASE WHEN columnName1 = colData THEN columnName2 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table 
WHERE columnName3 = 'ABC' and columnName4 = 'def' and columnName5 = 'fgh'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As suggested, added sample table with sample result as well..